# Entropy of a Rock with temperature change

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy

A hot rock ejected from a volcano's lava fountain cools from 1100º C to 40.0º C and its entropy decreases by 950 J/K. How much heat transfer occurs from the rock? (Source: OpenStax "College Physics for AP Students", Chapter 15.6)

My attempt

> [image]

However the correct answer is

> [image]

My answer is incorrect. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [Are check-my-work questions on-topic?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) for "check my work" problems.

Answer (score 1):

The correct equation for the change in entropy of the rock is $$\Delta S=MC\ln(313/1373)$$where M is the mass of the rock and C is the specific heat capacity.  You can use this equation to solve for MC.  The heat transferred is then MC(1100-40).

Comment: You solve for MC by setting $\Delta S$ in the equation equal to the 950.